# Extract dates, data from columns and fill empty data from text file in python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this. I'm new in python and the thing is that I have loads of .txt files from which I have to extract data from columns and put them all together into a single row including the date... each column of the file represents a month of the year and each row its value for the correspondent day (as you can see it in the following image)

```
         DIA       ENERO *  FEBRE *  MARZO *  ABRIL *  MAYO  *  JUNIO *  JULIO *  AGOST *  SEPTI *  OCTUB *  NOVIE *  DICIE *


       01                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0      5.0       .0
       02                                                     53.0      2.0       .0       .0       .0     10.0
       03                                                       .0     30.0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       04                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0     30.0       .0
       05                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       06                                                     24.0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       07                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0     17.0
       08                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       09                                                       .0     11.0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       10                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       11                                                      3.0       .0       .0     13.0       .0       .0
       12                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       13                                                       .0       .0       .0       .0     17.0       .0
       14                                              .0       .0       .0     18.0       .0      4.0     16.0
       15                                             6.0       .0       .0      3.0       .0       .0       .0
       16                                              .0       .0     32.0     10.0       .0       .0       .0
       17                                              .0       .0     17.0      8.0       .0       .0       .0
       18                                              .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0     52.0
       19                                             9.0       .0       .0      9.0     35.0       .0      2.0
       20                                             3.0       .0       .0       .0      5.0       .0       .0
       21                                              .0      5.0      2.0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       22                                              .0      9.0       .0       .0     10.0       .0    100.0
       23                                             1.0       .0       .0      1.6       .0       .0      6.0
       24                                             7.0       .0       .0       .0     27.0       .0       .0
       25                                            31.0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       26                                            52.0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       27                                              .0       .0       .0       .0       .0     14.0       .0
       28                                             2.0      3.0       .0       .0       .0       .0       .0
       29                                             2.0      9.0       .0       .0       .0     26.0       .0
       30                                              .0       .0       .0       .0     25.0       .0       .0
       31                                             3.0                .0     30.0                .0
```

as you can see, some of the data is missing, so I should add -99 to each missing data per day. In the end,  my file should look like this:

```
DATE            VALUE
01/01/1989      -99
01/02/1989      -99
01/03/1989      -99
.
.
.
05/14/1989      0.0
05/15/1989      6.0
.
.
12/31/1989      -99
```

I've tried to split each line of the file by '\t' and '  ' converting each line in a list in order to append columns later with no feasible results...

```
with open (file) as f:
for line in f:
   line = line.split(' ')
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the delimiter between the different columns then?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a poorly thought out format for keeping records. However, given this format perhaps your best bet is to record in a dictionary how many characters it is until you reach that category (i.e. {Enero: 15, etc}). Then for each line identify the numbers (numbers always have at least one space between them) and how many characters appeared before them. Then by trial and error you can see if the number of characters will correspond exactly to the value of one of the categories, or if not you can say if it is within 2 of the category then we'll treat it as belonging to that category. That should have a fairly high accuracy of sorting the numbers into the proper category, which seems like the most difficult element of this task.

Comment: completely agree with shitty formatting... what I've been doing is counting characters... let see what the output is... thx anyway...